# Set the second dimension of an array in a loop

Tags: vb.net

I want to dinamycally set the second array dimension depending on the first dimension in a for loop. I am not able to find any documentation for this right now. I don't mind being refered to the right place if anyone has it.

```
Dim array(3,0) As String
For y As Integer = 0 To array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1

            <<Set here the second dimension of the array to another dynamic variable 
            ( Something Like array(y).dimensionsize = X. Where y is my first dimension argument)>>

            For i As Integer = 0 To array.GetUpperBound(1) - 1
                array(y, i) = "something"
            Next
        Next
```

Is this possible?

EDIT:

The situation is that I get the group membership from the AD. user often have multiple account.

The first loop go through the number of account and the second one through the ad group in each of the account.

UserResult is the AD query result

This is the declaration at the begining since it goes through a backgroundworker. I need it to be global:

```
 Public Shared UserInfoGroup(1)() As String
```

The part i'm interested in within my backgroundworker.dowork:

```
 ReDim UserInfoGroup(UserResult.Count)(1)

        For y As Integer = 0 To UserResult.Count - 1

            Dim UserGroupArray As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = UserResult(y).GetGroups()
            ReDim UserInfoGroup(UserResult.Count)(UserGroupArray.Count)
            For i As Integer = 0 To UserGroupArray.Count - 1
                UserInfoGroup(y)(i) = UserGroupArray(i).ToString()
            Next
        Next
```

The backgroundworker.completed then output the array to the form.

Comment: Do you want it to be a jagged array (one where the number of columns is different for each row)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each "y" have different amount of "x" than you need a jagged array, not a 2D array.

```
Dim array(3)() As String

For y As Integer = 0 To array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1

    ReDim array(y)(x)
    ' or
    ' array(y) = New String(x) {}

    For i As Integer = 0 To x
        array(y)(i) = "something"
    Next
Next
```

A better option could be to have an array of list.

```
Dim array(3) As List(Of String)    

For y As Integer = 0 To array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1

    array(y) = New List(Of String)

    For i As Integer = 0 To x
        array(y).Add("something")
    Next
Next
```

Comment: shouldn't there be a Preserve after the ReDim of the first sample?

Comment: @sblandin no since the redim is done only on the second array

Comment: Seems like the best solution but I'm having a litle bit of a hard time implementing it.

I'm editing my post to show you.

Comment: What I needed was `UserInfoGroup(y) = New String(UserGroupArray.Count - 1) {}` to properly set each of the array on my loop. working fine now! thank you. You could edit the answer with that for future ref.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Redim Preserve array(3, x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not working as planned. It will set new bond with the one from the last loop.

Comment: When answering questions on SO, please make sure to explain why your answer works.  What does this code do?  How does it answer the question?  Why would OP try this instead of the original code or any of the other answers?